# Firebase Phone Auth Cost Analysis

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Am I getting charged only when the user receives an sms or is it considered as an authentication every time firebase wants to validate your session?

To clarify, I understand that you get free 10k verifications per month. But do I get billed (per month) for new authentications (those in excess of 10k) only? **OR** does firebase accumulate all authenticated users and charges for those in excess of 10k each month?

Answer (score 0):

*firebaser here*

As the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) says:

> Prices are per successful verification.

So the charge is per **verification**, and you get charged for the number of successful **verifications** per month (once that is larger than 10K).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would appreciate it if you clarify on the following;

So is a **verification** considered when the user receives an sms and uses the sent code?
 OR
 is it considered as a **verification** every time firebase wants to validate the user's session? more like, whenever the user is online to perform CRUD operations.

like, when does this **verification** occur?

That's where my dilemma resides. I hope you understand what I am trying to get across.

Comment: A verification is whenever the user completes a sign-in verification after you trigger it with something like this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone. Typically the user stays signed in after that, and you won't have to trigger another verification for them.

Comment: That answers my question. I just checked your profile and discovered you are an avenger, **Thank you**